# How do I get XCode to delete the app from the simulator when doing a clean build?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an iphone app, and while I'm in the early stages of development, I often need to delete the app from the simulator to reset the app's data.  I'd like to get XCode to do this automatically when I clean the source, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, with the help of this post on [Yeah Right Keller](http://yeahrightkeller.com/2009/run-script-while-cleaning-in-xcode/).  Setting an external build script as a dependency of your project lets a script get run when you clean your project.

Since that post was outdated, I wrote up new instructions for XCode 4.5.
http://nerglish.tumblr.com/post/40191311173/delete-app-from-simulator-when-cleaning-in-xcode

Here's the script I wrote to delete the app from the simulator

```
#!/bin/bash

# DeleteApp.sh
#
# Deletes iPhone app from the iOS Simulator when called with the clean action
#

APP_NAME="$PROJECT_NAME.app"

buildAction () {
echo "Building..."

# Don't do anything when building

}

cleanAction () {
echo "Cleaning..."

echo "Killing iPhone Simulator"
killall "iPhone Simulator"

# Change IFS to preserve spaces in the paths
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for appDir in $(find "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"/*/Applications -name "$APP_NAME")
do
    dir=$(dirname "$appDir")
    echo "Deleting $dir"
    rm -rf "$dir"
done
}

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# MAIN

echo "Running with ACTION=${ACTION}"

case $ACTION in
# NOTE: for some reason, it gets set to "" rather than "build" when
# doing a build.
"")
buildAction
;;

"clean")
cleanAction
;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: I would be very careful before running this script with `rm -rf` since your script could possibly delete a lot of files in that loop.  Might be better to echo which files you'll delete first and then uncomment the `rm -rf` once you're positive.